# Check a property on startup, depending on selected targets

Tags: msbuild

I'm having some trouble with a msbuild file.

I'd like the build to have three targets, executed in this order:

- `Cleanup`: Cleans the output of a previous build
- `Build`: The actual build
- `CopyFiles`: A task that packages the output of the build for an easier deployment

Now the problem is: I want a property (`ReleasePath`) for the `CopyFiles` target to be explicitly set by the caller. Also, the caller shouldn't have to set the output path if only calling the `Cleanup` and `Build` tasks.

My first try has been:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ReleasePath></ReleasePath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Initialize">
  <Error Text="The ReleasePath property isn't defined" Condition="'$(ReleasePath)' == ''"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyFiles" DependsOnTargets="Initialize">
</Target>
```

It works fine, but the `Initialize` target is executed right before `CopyFiles`, that is after `Build`. And the `Build`target can take quite a long time to execute, so if something's wrong I'd like the user to be notified right away.

**So basically, is there a way to run the `Initialize` target at the beginning, but only if `CopyFiles` is included in the targets?**

I also thought of putting `Initialize` in the `InitialTargets` attribute of the project, then put a condition to execute this target only if `CopyFiles` is selected, but to my surprise I couldn't find a property containing the list of targets selected by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish your goal would be to use a Property to toggle CopyFiles rather than the list of targets passed in.  If you always add CopyFiles to the AfterBuild target but condition it on a property like "ShouldCopyFiles" then you could also conditionalize the DependsOnTargets of Build:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
  <ShouldCopyFiles Condition="'$(ShouldCopyFiles)'==''">false</ShouldCopyFiles>
  <ReleasePath></ReleasePath>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup>
   <BuildDependsOn>
     BeforeBuild;
     CoreBuild;
     AfterBuild;
     CopyFiles;
   </BuildDependsOn>

 </PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ShouldCopyFiles)'=='true'">
    <BeforeBuildDependsOn>
     Initialize;
   </BeforeBuildDependsOn>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="Initialize" Condition="'$(ShouldCopyFiles)'=='true'">CheckStuff
 </Target>

 <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"/>

 <Target Name="CoreBuild">YourBuildStuff</Target>
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(BeforeBuildDependsOn)"/>
 <Target Name="AfterBuild" />

 <Target Name="CopyFiles" Condition="'$(ShouldCopyFiles)'=='true'">
   CopyStuff 
 </Target>
```

At this point you could call MSBuild like this:

```
 msbuild my.proj /targets:Clean;Build /p:ShouldCopyFiles=true
```

and that would toggle it on.

Comment: I was hoping for some magic trick to avoid adding another property, but I'm afraid you're right. Thanks!